# How to redirect external internet traffic from my IIS express server to another external website host

Tags: iis, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect traffic coming to my home server.

This should be such a simple task, but none of the samples I have found seems to do what I need.

I just want to bounce anything coming in for a specific url to a whole other server on the wwww.  Preferably preserving the domain name in the process.

I have IIS 2010 express installed on the server.  That does not seem to have HTTP Redirect installed.  Control Panel not offering to install it either.

Maybe I can do this with the dlink router?

I am running windows 10.  On Win 7 I could create a website that redirected to a new url, but for win 10 no can do.